# Cannot set service data inside subscribe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to set shared service data inside subscribe method my page structure is
[image]

i have to access data set from one component `app.component` in `home component` and `header component`.

```
 this.sharedService.setData({title: this.title, logo: this.logo});
```

> app.component.ts

```
  setData(): void {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'api/content').subscribe(result  => {
      this.title=result['response'].title;
      this.logo=result['response'].logo;
      this.sharedService.setData({title: this.title, logo: this.logo});
    }); 
    
  }
```

but in this case service data is set when i access it in any other component getting blank data for `title` and `logo` but when i pass static data (Not is subscribe method API call) then it's value is getting passed to other components.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export interface SharedData {
  title: string;
  logo: string;

}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SharedService  {

  private sharedData$ = new BehaviorSubject<SharedData>({title: '', logo: ''});
  sharedData = this.sharedData$.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setData(data: SharedData): void {
    this.sharedData$.next(data);
  }
}
```

Any Solution Thanks

Comment: Please, provide your code of getting/showing values in the header or the footer component. How do you subscribe to `sharedData` in them?

Comment: @NatalyChkhan `this.sharedService.sharedData.subscribe(result => this.data = result);` i'm using this code to subscribe to data service when the value is static it is passed to other component but as i put it in subscribe method the values are blank

Comment: Could you try `this.sharedService.sharedData.subscribe(result => {console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); this.data = result})` and look on console output? I am asking because your code should work correctly, seems like you miss something simple

Comment: @NatalyChkhan i checked the output first case if i have set all the data in my `app.component` and if i console this on the same component the data is returned but when i put this code in other component like `home` then the data is blank what can i see from console is `home` component is being called before `app.component` and the data is still not set after that `app.component` is called and it sets the data

Comment: In this case you need to check if these components use the same instance of `SharedService`. Do you have several NgModules in your app? Where is `SharedService` mentioned as Provider?

Comment: @NatalyChkhan I have included this service in `home` and `app.component` only, No other component is using this service

Comment: I have prepared a sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yejx9n?file=src/app/components/home.component.ts. This problem can be solved by understanding the difference between your app and this one.

Comment: @NatalyChkhan Thanks for static data it is working but when i put `setData()` inside my subscribe function `this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'api/content').subscribe(result  => {  ... setData()  });` then home page function getting blank data

Comment: @user3653474 There must be a little problem elsewhere then. I played a little with Nataly's Stackblitz even adding a `setTimeout` to simulate a delay in the response from the api, and even then, when the timeout fires, the `home.component` gets the data and updates the template correctly.

Comment: @user3653474 I can see you are trying to read `result['response'].title` and `result['response'].logo`: are you positive that your api returns an object with the property `response` or is that some residual code? Try removing that `['response']` bit and just putting `result.title` and `result.logo` instead...

Comment: @JuanDeLasNieves Yes response contains proper data, even if i assign some static value to title logo inside this block `this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'api/content').subscribe(result...` it does not work if i put this `this.sharedService.setData({title: this.title, logo: this.logo});` outside that `api call subscribe method` then it works for static values

Comment: @user3653474 Maybe I didn't explained myself well. I made an edit to my original answer, explayed better there. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BehaviourSubject` must be initialized with a starting value.

In your code you are starting with empty strings for `title` and `logo`, so, if you subscribe to it in any component before calling `setData` (which makes the get call), the new subscriber will get that initial "empty" value.

You could try replacing it with `ReplaySubject(1)`. Then, if `setData` has not been called yet at the moment of subscribing, you can apply whatever logic you need to make that call.

If you want to keep using `BehaviourSubject`, you can set the initial value to `null` and act accordingly in your subscribers.

** EDIT **

---

After playing a little with the Stackblitz set up by another user (and lacking the proper response object that your API is returning), I think the problem is not related to the Subjects or the subscription, but may be located in this two lines of your code:

```js
this.title=result['response'].title;
this.logo=result['response'].logo;
```

You could try to make the following changes in your `app.component.ts`:

```js
setData(): void {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'api/content').subscribe(result  => {
      /* Original code
      this.title=result['response'].title;
      this.logo=result['response'].logo;
      */ 
      
      /* New code */
      this.title=result.title;
      this.logo=result.logo;
      this.sharedService.setData({title: this.title, logo: this.logo});
    });     
}
```

Notice I simply removed the `['response']` property of the `result` object, as I'm *almost* positive there's no such property in what the API is returning to your app. But without seeing the *actual* response from your API, is difficult to give a proper answer.

Unless the response is an array, but in such case you would most likely need to point to an index position. Again, it would really help if you could paste the actual response from your API here so we could guide you better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer after setting the null values to all fields in service file will I get the value if the component subscribe before setData call or should I load all the initial data in service file only through api call so that if setData is not called then also I will get the data?

Comment: if I pass static data then  it is working but when I fetch from data inside subscribe method and pass set those data then getting empty values